# Unicity of solution to an integral equation

Tags: functional-equations, integral-equations

Suppose we have the following integral equation
$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty f(y)(x+y)e^{-x^2/2-xy}\text{d}y$$ where $f: [0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$. The function $f(x)=Ce^{-x^2/2}$ solves the equation. But is there a way to prove it is the unique solution?